# Not Skolem's Paradox - Part 2

Tags: logic, set-theory, peano-axioms

This is a followup to a previous question: [Not Skolem's Paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434196).

Assume we have a [countable, non-standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) of Peano Arithmetic in ZFC.

Let $N^*$ be the universe of this model and let $p \in N^*$ be a non-standard natural number larger than any standard natural number. In ZFC we can define the set $X = \{x : x \in N^* \land x < p\}$. Let $Y = X \cup \{p\}$. $X$ and $Y$ are both countably infinite sets and we can easily define a bijection between $X$ and $Y$ in ZFC. For example, we can define the set of ordered pairs:

$F = \{(0,p), (1,0), (2,1), (3,2), ...\}$.

My question is why doesn't the bijection $F$ exist inside the model?

In my previous question there was some confusion about how I was defining sets inside the model. We can encode any "finite" set of natural numbers as a natural number using powers of 2. For example, we can encode the set $\{1,2,3\}$ as $2^1+2^2+2^3=14$. Similarly, we can encode a bijection as a natural number. First, we define a method to encode an ordered pair as a natural number. Encode $(a,a)$ as $2^a$. Encode $(a,b)$ as $2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1}$ if $a<b$. If $b<a$ encode $(a,b)$ as $2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1} + 1$. Now that we can encode ordered pairs, we can define a bijection between two sets of natural numbers using [Godel's beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function).

My question becomes why doesn't some natural number in our model encode a function such that $F$ is an initial segment of this function?

Edit:

I want to thank Andres Caicedo for correcting my question. I do want to define my bijection as he suggests:

$F = \{(0,p)\} \cup \{(t+1,t) | t \in \aleph \} \cup \{ (s,s) | s \in X \backslash \aleph \}$

As he points out, I can't define $\aleph$, the set of standard natural numbers, inside the model. However, I can define $\aleph$ in my meta-theory. Can I come up a with beta function for $F$ inside ZFC? If so, does the encoding of this beta function exist in my model? If not, there is a natural number of the form $2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1} + 1$ that is missing from the model where $(a,b)$ is my beta function. If the encoding does exist in the model we have a definable violation of induction. Considering the alternatives, I am guessing there is some reason I can't define a beta function for $F$ in ZFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before going any further, note that $F$, as written, is most likely not what you meant it to be. It appears as if $F$ is a bijection between the standard part $\mathbb N$ of $N^*$, and the set $\mathbb N\cup\{p\}$. Note that this is a bijection, and it is the initial segment of some bijection between $X$ and $Y$ (for example, the one in  paragraph 3). This is not a problem. The issue is that the initial segment that codes $F$ is not definable in the model, it is not itself coded. The thing is, if $G$ is a function coded in $N^*$, with domain an initial segment of $N^*$, then for any initial segment $I$ *that is definable in $N^*$*, we have that in $N^*$ there is a code for $G\upharpoonright I$. But $I$ in this case is $\mathbb N$, and this is not definable in $N^*$. In fact, the only definable initial segments are those of the form $\{y\mid y<t\}$ for some $t$, and $\mathbb N$ definitely does not have this form. (This is proved by induction: "For any proper initial segment there is a least number not in it." The problem is that there is no least non-standard integer: IF $K$ is infinite, so is $K-1$.) The obstacle here is the restriction to definable initial segments, but this is unavoidable: If $G\upharpoonright I$ is coded in $N^*$, certainly $I$ is definable in $N^*$.

I imagine this $F$ is not what you intended. Rather, you probably meant something like $F=\{(0,p)\}\cup\{(t+1,t)\mid t<p\}$. But note that $(p,p-1)\in F$, so $F$ is a bijection alright, and certainly one coded inside $N^*$, but it is just a bijection from $Y$ to itself, which again is not what you intended.

Or maybe you meant $F=\{(0,p)\}\cup\{(t+1,t)\mid t\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(s,s)\mid s\in X\setminus\mathbb N\}$. This is definitely a bijection between $X$ and $Y$, but it is not definable in $N^*$, it is not encoded in there. If it were, we could from it define $\mathbb N$, and obtain a definable violation of induction.

In fact, no matter how we try, any bijection between $X$ and $Y$ cannot be coded within the model. This is because $N^*$, being a model of $\mathsf{PA}$, proves the appropriate facts about coded finite sets, such as there not being a bijection from a finite set to a proper superset. (This is proved by induction, of course.)

(If you find these explanations not quite satisfactory, and if you indicate any issues you may have, I'll try to clarify/expand/add as appropriate.)

---

Let me address your edit. The function $F$ in paragraph 3 is definitely an object in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. It is countable, so it can be coded as a set of numbers. However, we cannot code it inside the model. As Andreas Blass remarks, each value $(a,F(a))$ is certainly codable, but of course this is not enough. To have a coding of $F$ within $N^*$, via Gödel's approach or otherwise, we would need definability of $F$. As explained above, this gives us definability of $\mathbb N$ inside $N^*$. But this is impossible. In a sense, this is related to your previous question: $N^*$ can refer (via codes) only to sets that are fairly explicitly presented, and most sets are not. Even if "from the outside" we have a good understanding of $F$, this is simply an external object to our model $N^*$, it is "invisible" to it, and it is not possible to change this, because the induction schema prevents the presence of "Dedekind infinite integers".

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem with my bijection. I meant the bijection you give in paragraph 2. As you point out, this is a bijection from $Y$ to $Y$. Removing $(p,p1)$ would give a bijection from $X$ to $X$. I am not sure I understand why the the bijection in paragraph 3 can't be encoded. Are you assuming $Con(PA)$?

Comment: You are, I think. Otherwise, $N^*$ would not exist. Anyway, the point in paragraph 3 is that if $F$ were codable, then we could define $\mathbb N$ (since it is definable from $F$ as the set of $x$ in the domain of $F$ such that $F(x)\ne x$). But we argued in paragraph 1 that $\mathbb N$, being an initial segment of $N^*$, is not definable since it is not the set of predecessors of some number. Since $\mathbb N$ is not definable, we cannot have a way of coding $F$.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, I am trying to "obtain a definable violation of induction". I like your answer, but I usually wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. I originally assumed the answer would involve [Tennenbaum's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the edited version of the question, with the corrected version of $F$: The function $F$ exists in the ZFC universe, and (therefore) so does the corresponding set of codes in $N^*$ of the ordered pairs in $F$. But this subset of $N^*$ is not coded by any member of $N^*$, for the reason in Andres Caicedo's answer: If it were codable, then there would be a definable violation of induction, meaning that $N^*$ is not really a model of Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: If $F$ exists in ZFC, what prevents me from encoding it **IN ZFC** as, say, a beta function? If this code does not exist in the model then I can still prove $N^*$ is not a model of PA. I would be able to show there is a number of the form $2^{a+1} + 2^{b+1} + 1$ that is missing from the model.

Comment: @RussellEasterly (1) In ZFC, you can encode, via the beta function, finite sets of natural numbers as natural numbers. $F$ is, however, an infinite set in the ZC universe. (2) The "numbers" of the form $2^{a+1}+2^{b+1}+1$ that code ordered pairs are in the model; what is not available in the model is a code for the set of those ordered pairs that constitute $F$.

Comment: @Andeas Blass: Which sets of ordered pairs can I encode? How is this set different from any other set? There are lots of ways I can encode this bijection. I could use the Godel number of a Turing machine. I could encode it as a string of characters, "(0,p)(1,0),...,(p-1,p-1)". Are you saying none of these possible encodings exist as numbers in the model?

Comment: @RussellEasterly I was referring to the standard encoding, but in fact the same goes for any other reasonable encoding. If you allow unreasonable encodings then you could define a coding system where 0 is defined to be a code of the $F$ you want; but then the usual manipulations of codes (e.g., checking whether one given number is in the set coded by another given number) would not be definable in the model. As to which sets can be encoded, that depends on the particular model that you're working in, but in no case can you code something that would violate the induction axioms.